# Angular5 app needs hard refresh when changing pages or javascript stops working

Tags: angular

I ported a html/css **template** with some javascript into angular 5 and am noticing a key feature aren't working as expected.

Essentially features like the **modals and image gallery** which rely heavily on javascript, stop working after calling angular router.

So if navigate from page one, where the javascript is working fine to page two, the **javascript doesn't get called** and a hard refresh is needed.

I'm routing in the standard way, so I researched around a lot but can't find out whats missing.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SliderComponent } from './home/slider/slider.component';


const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'slider', component: SliderComponent}
];

export const routingComponents = [
    HomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SliderComponent,
    DealsComponent,
    FeaturedProductsComponent,
    PopularBrandsComponent,
    PromisesComponent,
    FooterComponent
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [
  ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and **angular-cli.json** contains

```
"scripts": ["assets/js/vendor.min.js", "assets/js/scripts.min.js", "assets/js/modernizr.min.js", "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"]
```

Example of javascript usage - through classes.

```
     <!-- Poduct Gallery-->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="product-gallery">
          <div class="gallery-wrapper">
            <div class="gallery-item video-btn text-center"><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-type="video" data-video="&lt;div class=&quot;wrapper&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;video-wrapper&quot;&gt;&lt;iframe class=&quot;pswp__video&quot; width=&quot;960&quot; height=&quot;640&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/CjNjcrQZtd8&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" title="Watch video"></a></div>
          </div><span class="product-badge bg-danger">Sale</span>
          <div class="product-carousel owl-carousel gallery-wrapper">
            <div class="gallery-item" data-hash="one"><a href="assets/img/shop/single/01.jpg" data-size="1000x667"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/01.jpg" alt="Product"></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item" data-hash="two"><a href="assets/img/shop/single/02.jpg" data-size="1000x667"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/02.jpg" alt="Product"></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item" data-hash="three"><a href="assets/img/shop/single/03.jpg" data-size="1000x667"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/03.jpg" alt="Product"></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item" data-hash="four"><a href="assets/img/shop/single/04.jpg" data-size="1000x667"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/04.jpg" alt="Product"></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item" data-hash="five"><a href="assets/img/shop/single/05.jpg" data-size="1000x667"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/05.jpg" alt="Product"></a></div>
          </div>
          <ul class="product-thumbnails">
            <li class="active"><a href="#one"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/th01.jpg" alt="Product"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#two"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/th02.jpg" alt="Product"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#three"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/th03.jpg" alt="Product"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#four"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/th04.jpg" alt="Product"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#five"><img src="assets/img/shop/single/th05.jpg" alt="Product"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The two customs javascript files from the template are minified not much use posting here.

Comment: how are you using javascript? in component? can you post the code

Comment: no it's just in the index.html `  <script src="assets/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/scripts.min.js"></script>`

Comment: try to add the scripts in  angular-cli.json like this - "scripts": [
        "assets/js/vendor.min.js"
      ],

Comment: nope that didn't do it. thanks

Comment: can you see if the scripts are initialized on window load event?

Comment: I can't find the window load event in chrome developer tools? I can see the js file in the sources tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172630/discussion-between-yer-and-kaigo).

Comment: What are you using for the modals and image gallery? Please update the question with this information and the proper tags.